# Hibernate : throw exception in @PostUpdate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this code on an Spring/Hibernate webapp :

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
@EntityListeners(ArticleEntityListener.class)
public class ArticleLocaliseBean extends EntiteTracee {
...
```

Listenner :

```
public class ArticleLocaliseEntityListener {
@PostUpdate
@PostPersist
private void checkQuantite(ArticleBean article) throws BusinessException {
    if (article.getQuantiteStock() < 0) {
        throw new BusinessException(exceptionMsg);
    }
}
```

This code called after each update or persist on `Article` entity.
The problem is when an exception is thrown for negative quantity, hibernate convert the `BusinessException` on a `RuntimeException` and perform a rollback of the transaction.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: xxx.exceptions.BusinessException: exceptionMsg.
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.ListenerCallback.invoke(ListenerCallback.java:53)
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.callback(EntityCallbackHandler.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.postUpdate(EntityCallbackHandler.java:83)
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.handlePostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:70)
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.onPostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:62)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:199)
```

How can I makes Hibernate throw a checked exception an not a Runtime ? I don't want a rollback of the transaction when an exception is thrown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown upon call on an API method, such as [persist()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist(java.lang.Object)). These methods however are not declared to throw exceptions (there is no `throws` clause in their signature). Hibernate has to wrap any checked exception in a runtime exception to respect method's signature.

To avoid rolling back, you can catch the runtime exception and check for its cause.

```
try {
    em.persist(entity);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof BusinessException) {
        // Fix the problem the way you want
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```